# how to write an inline llvm pass

Tags: optimization, inline, llvm

I want to write an llvm pass in order to make inline optimization therefore I call the method getAnalysis() but I have Segmentation fault.. Why? this is the code I am using:

```
using namespace llvm;
namespace {

  struct MyInline : public ModulePass {

static char ID;
MyInline2() : ModulePass(ID) {}

virtual bool runOnModule(Module &M) {
  errs() << "Hello2: ";
  CallGraph &CG = getAnalysis<CallGraph>();

  return false;
}
  };
}
char MyInline::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<MyInline> X("MyInline", "MyInline Pass", false, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `getAnalysis()`, you must first override [`getAnalysisUsage()`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Pass.html#a048082a5be9ae0d8901ea64de59e5c8f), presumably to have the necessary analysis data set up for you.

> getAnalysisUsage - This function should be overriden by passes that
>   need analysis information to do their job. If a pass specifies that it
>   uses a particular analysis result to this function, it can then use
>   the getAnalysis() function, below.